# Create & Prove Conjecture - Discrete Math (Proofs)

Tags: proof-writing, conjectures

I am stuck on the following problem:

> Imagine that a building has been overrun with snakes and rats. To help
>   curb the problem, the building manager decides to offer employees
>   brownie points for capturing and relocating them. They offer 13 points
>   for each snake and 6 points for each rat captured and removed.
>
> 1. Make a conjecture about what totals for points are possible. For example, an employee could not earn 7 points in this scenario.
> 2. Prove that your conjecture is true.

What "conjecture" am I supposed to be making? I assume I am trying to find a fact/pattern; something like "*points can only be obtained in multiples of 6*", but I am lost. I only managed to find that the two provided numbers, 6 and 13, are relatively prime.

Of course, I also need to figure out how to prove such conjecture, I just can't do that until after I make it.

---

**Edit:** Okay, I totally misread the example conjecture. So my conjecture will be "*an employee could not earn 14 points in this scenario*". I write the following proof:

*Proof*: The two values of obtainable points are 6 and 13. The first 5 possible combinations of sums of 6 and 13 are, in order, as follows:

```
{ (0), (6), (6+6), (13), (13+6), (6+6+6) } = { 0, 6, 12, 13, 18 }
```

There are no possible combinations of sums of 6 and 13 that equate to 14. Therefore, it is impossible for an employee to earn 14 points in this scenario.

Comment: My best suggestion right now would be: Conjecture: Every point total is of the form $6n+13m+78k$ with $n\in\{0,...,12\}$, $m\in\{0,...,5\}$ and $k\in\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: @m450n You may find the [Coin problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coin_problem) information somewhat helpful.